# Make one list from two list applying constraint

Tags: python, list

I have two list A,B

```
A = [2,3,1,4,5,2,4]
B = [4,2,3,6,2,5,1]
```

I want to combine this A and B like:

```
C = [2,4,2,3,1,3,4,6,2,5,2,5,1,4]
```

rules:

1. A[i]<=B[i], take A[i], then B[i]
2. A[i]>B[i], take B[i], then A[i]

I can do this using loop like below:

```
C = []

for a,b in zip(A,B):
    if(a<=b):
        C.append(a)
        C.append(b)
    else:
        C.append(b)
        C.append(a)
```

This actually works. How Can i do this in following way:

```
 C = [ [a,b if (a<=b)],[ b,a else] for a,b in zip(A,B)] # This is totally wrong
```

But how can i do this using if-else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are doing it is good because it is very readable... but if a one-liner is what you are after the I will oblige:

```
>>> A = [2,3,1,4,5,2,4]
>>> B = [4,2,3,6,2,5,1]
>>> [i for sublist in [[a, b] if a < b else [b, a] for a, b in zip(A, B)] for i in sublist]
[2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4]
```

Few notes:

1. When you add a conditional to a list comp, have the `if - else` right after the first variable in the list comp.  `['a' if i in (2, 4, 16) else 'b' for i in [1, 2, 3, 16, 24]]`
2. The best way to construct (mentally) nested list comprehensions is to think of it how you would write it in a normal loop.

---

```
C = [[a, b] if a < b else [b, a] for a, b in zip(A, B)]
for sublist in C:
    for i in sublist:
        yield i
```

Then you just flatten the nested loops and move the `yield i` to the front, dropping the `yield`.

```
for sublist in C for i in sublist yield i
|-> yield i for sublist in C for i in sublist
    |-> i for sublist in C for i in sublist
```

Now you can just replace C with the list comp above and get the one-liner I posted.

Comment: Oh.. Thank you very much. This is your answer. I get it

Comment: for sublist in C for i in sublist i and i for sublist in C for i in sublist -- can i use both?

Comment: No, the `[item_in_sublist for sublist in C for item_in_sublist in sublist]` is the **correct** and **valid** syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`,

```
import itertools 
A = [2,3,1,4,5,2,4]
B = [4,2,3,6,2,5,1]  
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i if i[0]<=i[1] else (i[1], i[0]) for i in zip(A, B)))
```

or sort the `tuple` You are getting by zipping two list `zip(A, B)`

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sorted(i) for i in zip(A, B)))
```

See the time diffrence using `List Comprehension`, `map`, `sorted`

```
In [70]: %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i if i[0]<=i[1] else (i[1], i[0]) for i in zip(A, B)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.49 µs per loop

In [71]: %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sorted(i) for i in zip(A, B)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.81 µs per loop

In [72]: %timeit [i for sublist in [[a, b] if a < b else [b, a] for a, b in zip(A, B)] for i in sublist]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.28 µs per loop

In [73]: %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x:x[1]>x[0] and (x[0],x[1]) or (x[1],x[0]),zip(A,B))))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.26 µs per loop
```

Comment: I think as the number of elements increases the itertools solution gets more performant compared to the nested for loops solution I posted.  But from what I recall, it takes a pretty large data set.  Though, personally, I still prefer the itertools solution as well.  One of my favorite modules.

Comment: @sberry At large items in lists, itertools preferred that's why i used `itertools` here.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay, yeah - but needs to be **very** large to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this?

```
C = sum([[a,b] if a <= b else [b, a] for (a,b) in zip(A,B)], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x:x[1]>x[0] and (x[0],x[1]) or (x[1],x[0]),zip(A,B))))
[2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4]
```

Comment: I did't get it. Can you explain please

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
C = [sorted([a, b]) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

and concatenate all the elements of C.

Comment: This is your result: [[2, 4], [2, 3], [1, 3], [4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 5], [1, 4]]

Comment: Elements of C must be concatenated to produce final result. Don't you read the full post?